# Remove duplicate numbers separated by a symbol in a string using Hive's REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, hive, sparklyr

I have a spark dataframe with a string column that includes numbers separated by `;`, for example: `862;1595;17;862;49;862;19;100;17;49`, I would like to remove the duplicated numbers, leaving the following: `862;1595;17;49;19;100`

As far as patterns go I have tried

1. `"\\b(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?) ([^;]+); (?=.*\\b\\1 \\2\\b)`
2. `(?<=\b\1:.*)\b(\w+):?`
3. `\\b(+)\\b(?=.*?\\b\1\\b)`
4. `(\b[^,]+)(?=.*, *\1(?:,|$)), *`

But nothing has yielded what I need thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query (to replace duplicate numbers in a string column):

```
SELECT  regexp_replace
        (
            your_column,
            '(?<=^|;)(?<num>.*?);(?=.*(?<=;)\\k<num>(?=;|$))',
            ''
        )

FROM table;
```